# how to delete english text in picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

[image]

hi this is scanned picture and  i want to delete English text in the picture and other(Persians text) should remains
what should I  do?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is that faiing?

Comment: You will need to delete it manually. Raster images of text don't contain any actual editable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop can see what's white and what's black, but it cannot see what's in English and what's not. If it's a scanned image Photoshop even cannot decide what's writing and what's a decorative shape. You must make the difference.  You can for ex. paint white on the English text or paste white shapes on them - you only move and stretch pasted shapes right. An example:

[image]

A bunch of rectangular selection marquees are drawn by holding the Shift key, the selection is filled with color by clicking with the paint bucket once. Grey is used instead of white to show the result.

In theory a Persian capable optical character recognition program (=OCR, no idea of any product with such capability) could find Persian words and letters which could be copied to elsewhere, but everything must still be inspected manually because 100,00% reliable OCR is nonexistent.